# What is the equivalent of `keyof` for an ES `Map` type?

Tags: typescript

Given a TypeScript `Map`, it's easy to figure out what the type of the keys is-just use `keyof`:

```
// keyof
type MyRec = Record<string, number>;
type MyRecKey = keyof MyRec; // works
```

What is the equivalent of `keyof` for `Map`? Is there something built in to the TS standard library?

```
// MapKeyOf ?
type MyMap = Map<string, number>;
type MyMapKey = MapKeyOf<MyMap>; // is there a built-in way to do this?
```

Due to the glorious expressiveness of TypeScript, this is expressible in user-land, but I don't want to have to copy/paste this or may a `type-utils` file:

### Update: this question previously had a more complicated user-land definition

```
type KeyOfMap<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>> = M extends Map<infer K, unknown> ? K : never
```

> this solution is from @TitianCernicova-Dragomir and @kaya3

Comment: There is no keyword that privileges the Map type. You need to do it in "userland". But a simpler userland solution is `type KeyOfMap<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>> = M extends Map<infer K, unknown> ? K : never`.

Comment: updated the question to use your solution, thanks @kaya3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in type to to this. The TS team are very conservative about adding new utility types (`Omit` was the last one added and it was not without controversy). The guidance is use a type utility library or use your own,

I would suggest that writing `MapOf` is just a simple conditional type, not sure why you need your more complex solution:

```
type KeyOfMap<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>> = M extends Map<infer K, unknown> ? K : never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIHkBmBZAhmAPCqEAewEAdgCYDOU6WArkQNZED2A7kQDRS0MtEB8vUALyVcBYuUoZMASyJIIAJ1gcuTVgID8sKAC4oRCADdFAKFCRKIKkMlYywBbIDmHItQC2AI0W8A3GfBoFCsMOBAbMOQqbBCwPygoAHpEqABlB2cTEyA)

Comment: This solution is way better, and the same as the one from a comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60737502/what-is-the-equivalent-of-keyof-for-an-es-map-type#comment107461242_60737502.  Don't let me near generics before I've had coffee, I will overcomplicate them!

Comment: How about `ValueOfMap` ?

Comment: I've actually extracted this into a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73515495/what-is-the-equivalent-of-tkeyof-t-for-an-es-map-type