# Type guard for Map in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

consider Map like this in file `CategoryMap.ts`

```
export default new Map<number, SubCategory[]>([
   [11, [100, 101]],
   [12, [102, 103]],
   ...
])
```

How to make type guard for that Map?

```
import categoryMap from 'CategoryMap'

type CategoryMapId = keyof typeof categoryMap

function isCategoryId(id: number): id is CategoryMapId {
   return categoryMap.has(id)
}
```

This doesn't work because `CategoryMapId` is 
`"[Symbol.toStringTag]" | "clear" | "delete" | "forEach" | "get" | "has" | "set" | "size" | "[Symbol.iterator]" | "entries" | "keys" | ...`

I expect that type `CategoryMapId` is `11 | 12 ...`

Any solutions? Thanx.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a type for the 'key' of the map like so:

```js
const testMap = new Map<11 | 12, [number, number]>([
  [11, [100, 101]],
  [12, [102, 103]],
]);

const y = testMap.get(11); // works
const x = testMap.get(13); // type error
```

However it seems that you want to have typescript infer this at runtime. Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60737746/5011469), it seems we can do something like:

```js
type KeyOfMap<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>> = M extends Map<infer K, unknown> ? K : never

const testMap = new Map<number, [number, number]>([
  [11, [100, 101]],
  [12, [102, 103]],
]);

type CategoryMapId = KeyOfMap<typeof testMap>;

const isCategoryId = (id: number): id is CategoryMapId =>
  testMap.has(id);
```

But in that case, `CategoryMapId` still just has the type `number`, which isn't what we want.

Using an object instead of a Map, you have the option to get a proper type for the keys:

```js
const testMap = {
  11: [100, 101],
  12: [102, 103],
}
type CategoryMapId = keyof typeof testMap;

const isCategoryId = (id: number): id is CategoryMapId =>
  Object.keys(testMap).map(Number).indexOf(id) > -1;

const x = isCategoryId(11); // true
const y = isCategoryId(13); // false

const getValue = (id: number) => {
  if (isCategoryId(id)) {
    return testMap[id];
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}
```

This may not fit your use case, but it seems impossible to do this with Maps currently

Comment: Yes, I thought that object is only way to achieve this. But maybe is better type guard like that: `return id in testMap` instead of `Object.keys(testmap).map(...) ...`

Comment: Actually `as const` can do the trick [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBALgpgzlAsiADhAvBAdjA7hZFACgG0AoCSkgRmoBoIaAGJh6p6gXU7oquoBMDZkIjsAzN16cIIOBADGAeywIAlGTJQAnihgQA0jG0B5AGaEAPIggwAHrCwATeVYCuWANZYluLAw9vXywAPhCMAlsHGGdXVEsASywzGEgDAK8fP3CAfkMIAC5sGGBUzR09CABhEFgAcyUwbUIASScIo1MLeIqYJTNoeCRUEIBuTWVVKAgEuBr6xu02iKIEpyKsNwBbACNUtSK1mfl5mAam1vb0EL5YBEIAOgALOVX2uWras8XLtXGgA)