# What is the equivalent of `T[keyof T]` for an ES `Map` type?

Tags: typescript

Given an object, in TypeScript it's easy to figure out what the type of the values is-just use `T[keyof T]`:

```
type MyRec = Record<string, number>;
type MyRecValue = MyRec[keyof MyRec]; // number
```

What is the equivalent of `T[keyof T]` for `Map`? Is there something built in to the TS standard library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in type to to this. You need to write your own helper:

```
type ValueOfMap<M extends Map<unknown, unknown>> = M extends Map<unknown, infer V> ? V : never
```

Now it will work:

```
type MyMap = Map<string, number>;
type MyMapValue = ValueOfMap<MyMap>; // number
```

Thanks to this answer for helping me figure it out:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60737746/2697506

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the return type of `.get` to see what type it returns and get the value. You can also examine the argument type `.get` accepts to get the key.

```
const m = new Map<number, string>();
type M = typeof m;
type Key = Parameters<M["get"]>[0]; // number
type Value = ReturnType<M["get"]; // string | undefined
```

Comment: Interesting solution! I would've never thought of this.