# Typescript: How to get union type from js Map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am unable to create union type from Map. Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
const myMap = new Map ([
  ['one', <IconOne/>],
  ['two', <IconTwo/>],
  ['three', <IconThree/>],
]);
// I know i can make it not like Map. But I have data like Map, and can't change it now.

type Props = {
  name: 'one' | 'two' | 'three'; 
  // i need this type here, but have no idea how to make this type from map keys
  // tryed use "typeof" "keyof" but have no idea how to do it right 
}

export const Component = ({name}: Props) => (
   <div>
    {myMap.get(name)}
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change the `Map` definition to use `as const` (otherwise you just get `string` as the key type), then you can write

```
const myMap = new Map ([
  ['one', <IconOne/>],
  ['two', <IconTwo/>],
  ['three', <IconThree/>],
] as const);

type Props = {
  name: typeof myMap extends Map<infer K, any> ? K : never;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the correct answer from @Bergi: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887764/15076557

Below is my attempt to an answer — maybe other methods I provided will be helpful to someone else.

---

I don't think you can do this with your setup.

If you look at the type of `myMap`, it will be `Map<string, string>` — typescript doesn't narrow this type to any of your keys or values. So, even a solution like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60737746/15076557) would not help, meaning you likely will have to bring out the data you pass to `Map` to some variable/type in one way or another.

---

Now, one of the closest solutions might be taking out the keys to a separate type and then using it in `myMap` and `Props`:

```
type Key = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

const myMap = new Map<Key, string> ([
  ['one', '123'],
  ['two', '456'],
  ['three', '345'],
]);
// I know i can make it not like Map. But I have data like Map, and can't change it now.

type Props = {
  name: Key; 
  // i need this type here, but have no idea how to make this type from map keys
  // tryed use "typeof" "keyof" but have no idea how to do it right 
}
```

Another way is to define the keys and values using an array and `as const` assertion to narrow the types, and infer them into a separate type, and once again use it in `myMap` and `Props`:

```
const myMapAsArr = [
  ['one', '123'],
  ['two', '456'],
  ['three', '345'],
] as const;

type Key = typeof myMapAsArr[number][0];

const myMap = new Map(myMapAsArr);

type Props = {
  name: Key;
  // i need this type here, but have no idea how to make this type from map keys
  // tryed use "typeof" "keyof" but have no idea how to do it right 
}
```